# Why does if-let need wrapping with Some?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and just came across the nice `if-let` construct. I have values `a` and `b` which are both `Option`. I use `if-let` as follows:

```
if let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (a, b) {
    println!("You passed in {:?}, {:?}");
}
```

This works but I am confused about why I need wrap my values like `Some(a)` which are already an `Option`.

Isn't `Option` already one of `Some` or `None` ?

Comment: Relevant section from the book: [Chapter 6, section 3 on Concise control flow with if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-03-if-let.html#concise-control-flow-with-if-let)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the places when you use *pattern matching* in rust. In simpler example:

```rust
let x: Option<i32> = Some(42);

if let Some(x) = x {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Rust knows that `x` is a type `Option` and this being an enum has two possible variants. So what this pattern matching express is to look at `x` and compare it to `Some(x)`. If `x` is `None` that the matching will fail (because `None` and `Some(_)` are different variants). But if `x` is `Some` than the pattern will match **and value inside of `Some` will be assigned to variable `x`**. This will in turn *shadow* previous variable `x` and be only valid inside this `if let` scope.

What you are doing is practically the same, only you match as a pattern a tuple of two Options. Read this [chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html) from The Book on pattern matching to understand it better and see all the other places you can find it in rust.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to be aware of here is that you're not wrapping your values. When you use `if let Some(x) = y {` you are testing if the variable `y` matches the pattern `Some(x)` and if it does, binds the value of `x` to be the thing wrapped by the option. You can read up on pattern matching in the book [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html)

In your example, the fact you used `a` and `b` on both sides is a little misleading. You are [shadowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html?highlight=shadow#shadowing) your original variables with new variables. You could have written `if let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (a, b) {` and it would have worked but `a` and `b` would still have been options and `x` and `y` would have been available as the previously wrapped values.

Also, your print statement needs to have `a` and `b` passed in. Presumably your original code did have them.

Answer (score 1):

You're unpacking the contents of a "maybe-`Some`" to the value it holds, and only entering the block if both were `Some`. If you could just write `if let (a, b) = (a, b)`, how would it know to unpack (rather than just copy) and to not run at all when it's `None`? Your code is performing meaningful work, both testing for `Some`ness and unpacking (and shadowing) the original `a` and `b` with the contents of the `Some` object they originally held. If you didn't have `Some`, neither the test nor the unpacking would be something Rust could infer on its own.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets forget the tuple for a moment, it is just noise for this issue.

You do not need to wrap them, you can do:

```
if let a = a {
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

But what would be the point of the `if`? In Rust such an assignment never fails!

In fact, when you write a `let LEFT = RIGHT;`, the `LEFT` part is technically called a *binding*, that is a special syntax that *binds* names (variables) to values.

In general bindings may be fallible, if you type `let Some(inner_a) = a;` then if `a` is `Some(42)` then `inner_a` will bind to `42`; but what if `a` is None`, the variable` inner_a` will be unassigned, and that is not good.

The usual way to tackle that is with a match, that tries multiple bindings until one succeeds:

```
let inner_a = match a {
    Some(x) => x,
    None => 0,
};
```

The `if let` construct is just syntactic sugar for a match:

```
if let Some(inner_a) = a {
    do_something(inner_a);
}
```

is desugared to:

```
match a {
    Some(inner_a) => {
        do_something(inner_a);
    }
    _ => {} //catch-all binding
}
```

**TL;DR;** The `Some()` at the left of a `=` is not *wrapping* the value, it is *unwrapping* it!.